# Block servlet access to the file system or other Java core libraries in Jetty (like Google App Engine)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jetty

GAE uses Jetty, and it prevents access to the file system from servlets.

I was wondering if limiting acces to core Java libraries from servlets can be accomplished in your own Jetty setup...is something like this done through configuring/customizing Jetty or is there a "servlet sandbox add-on" for Jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Jetty uses](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Secure_Mode) the [standard Java security model](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html), just [like Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html).